# why don't I get return value optimization in this code?

Tags: c++, constants, copy-constructor

Could anyone explain to me the 5th line of the output? I don't understand why the `MyClass` object `b` doesn't get assigned returned object `c` from the `func`.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int x;
    std::string s;

    MyClass(const MyClass &other);
    MyClass();
    void output();
};

MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &other): x(2), s("s?") { }
MyClass::MyClass() : x(1), s("s1") { }

void MyClass::output() { cout << x << " " << s << endl; }

MyClass func(MyClass c) //MyClass c = Myclass(a)
{
    cout << "2. in func: "; c.output();
    c.s = "s2";
    cout << "3. in func: "; c.output();
    return c;
}

int main() 
{
    MyClass a;
    cout << "1. "; a.output();
    MyClass b = func(a);
    cout << "4. "; a.output();  
    cout << "5. "; b.output();
}
```

The output is:

```
1. 1 s1
2. in func: 2 s?
3. in func: 2 s2
4. 1 s1
5. 2 s?
```

I understand where do lines 1-4 come from, but I don't get why at the end, the `MyClass b.s` has a value of `s?` not the `s2`. Is it because the `const` object is created within the `func` scope?

EDIT:
I know that the copy constructor is called when `MyClass c` object is initialized within the `func` scope, but how the returned object is not assigned to `b` ?

Comment: it is not s2 because `MyClass b = func(a);` calls the copy constructor for `b` which initializes the string member to `s?`

Comment: I think you may need to clarify why you're surprised by the output. Your question is more subtle than you probably realise, and none of the answers have picked up on that. Hint: an alternative title could be "why don't I get *return value optimization* in this code?"

Comment: @juanchopanza that's done, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why don't I get return value optimization in this code?

The reason is that your function is returning `c`, which is a parameter. Even though it is a value, and therefore a local object in the function, this is one of the cases in which [return value optimization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (in this case, *named return value optimization*, or NRVO) is not permitted by the C++ standard. If you were to create a local copy of `c`, RVO would be allowed:

```
MyClass func(MyClass c) //MyClass c = Myclass(a)
{
    MyClass d = c;
    cout << "2. in func: "; d.output();
    d.s = "s2";
    cout << "3. in func: "; d.output();
    return d;
}
```

With those changes, I get the following using a recent clang++:

> 1. 1 s1
> 2. in func: 2 s?
> 3. in func: 2 s2
> 4. 1 s1
> 5. 2 s2

Answer (score 3):

```
MyClass b = func(a);
```

That line will call the copy constructor of `MyClass` to create `b` from `a`. Although it has an `=`, it does *not* call the assignment operator; the object hasn't been created yet, so there's nothing to assign to.

An object doesn't need to be `const` to bind to a `const T&`, even temporaries can bind to them.

Comment: So, what happens with the object returned by the `func` ?

Comment: @MaTi It's destroyed at the end of that full expression.

Comment: @Ma Ti It will get destroyed, try creating your user defined destructor to see what's happening.

Comment: @PcAF I have added print statements in the destructor and constructor and it helped me to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You return a local variable c in func. It gets copy constructed, to be copied into b. Your copy constructor specifies s="s?" so that's what it's being set as.

Comment: so does it get 'copy constructed' at the beginning and and the end of the function?

Comment: yes. Once to be passed to the function, and once to be returned.